# Unable to use multiple outputs in Zsh without tee

Tags: zsh, tee

I have the following in .zshrc

```
setopt multios
```

I am trying to do the following with the above option enabled in Zsh

```
ls -1 | tee file.txt | less
```

I run the following command unsuccessfully

```
ls -1 | file.txt | less
```

and the following too

```
ls -1, file.txt, less
```

**How can you use multiple outputs in Zsh without the command tee?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second one is the wrong syntax, it should be

```
ls -1 > file.txt | less
```